# Showing an image calling the name of the picture in the database

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to show a picture from a path in the database. I query the database and find the name of the picture like this.
**html**

```
<img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="images/show_image.cfm" width="48" height="48"/>
```

**show_image.cfm**

```
<cfquery name="grab_image">
   SELECT picture
   FROM dbo.Users
   WHERE employee_number = <cfqueryparam value="#session.employee_number#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
 </cfquery>

<cfdump var="#grab_image#">
```

I am trying to figure out how to have this query finish the path. so that it will read src="images/(image name)" by doing src="images/calling the show_image.cfm" Is this possible?

When I call the query I get an array like this:[image]

Am I able to show a picture this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe so.

You are effectively placing an entire query inside the `img` tag along with a dump of its structure, but not the query's result.

It would be much, much easier to run the query then output like so.

```
<cfquery name="grab_image">
   SELECT picture
   FROM dbo.Users
   WHERE employee_number = <cfqueryparam value="#session.employee_number#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
</cfquery> 

<cfoutput query="grab_image">
<img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="images/#picture#" width="48" height="48"/>
</cfoutput>
```

Though, if the image files themselves have a common naming convention, you shouldn't even need a database to load them.

Answer (score 5):

The image [`SRC`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/img) should be a URL which returns an *image*, rather than a string path which *points to* an image. So if you absolutely must do it this way, you would need to read in the image as binary. Then return it from show_image.cfm with [cfcontent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c82.html):

```
<cfset imgContent = FileReadBinary( "The Full path to the image" )>
<cfcontent type="image/jpeg" variable="#imgContent#">
```

That said, unless there is a good reason you must keep the two separate, it would be much simpler to use a single .cfm page (not HTML) and simply build a string path from your query data using cfoutput:

```
<img src="images/#yourQuery.theFileName#" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks :)  It is probably overkill here, but you can do some interesting stuff with the [good old cfcontent/image trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052429/how-to-record-url-variables-query-string-from-an-img-src-attribute-on-the-serv/21052743#21052743) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do something like this:

```
<cfquery name="grab_image">
    SELECT picture
    FROM dbo.Users
    WHERE employee_number = <cfqueryparam value="#session.employee_number#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
</cfquery>

<cfif grab_image.RecordCount EQ 1>
    <cfoutput>
        <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="images/#grab_image.picture#" width="48" height="48"/>
    </cfoutput>
<cfelse>
    <!--- no image or more than one image --->
</cfif>
```

*this is pseudo code - not tested*